# c# position counter in a stream reader

Tags: c#, position, text-files, streamreader

Developing a small quiz application, thus far I have a text file containing two example questions to see if i can get it working properly before adding more. There are 5 question levels of increasing difficulty, each of these levels contains 10 questions

I'm using a streamreader to read my level 1 questions in from the text file, it reads the first question in fine and the program reads user input and compares it to the answer. If correct the user will move to the next level, but if incorrect I want the program to ask the second question in the file - but it continues to read the first.

I have

```
static int pos = 0;
```

serving as my position counter for the reader, but whenever I try to include the position when addressing my struct in the reader like

```
_question1[pos].q_No = Convert.ToInt32(sreader.ReadLine());
```

I get an error message:

```
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 
'Quiz_Application.Program.question1'
```

Variables n stuff:

```
static question1[] _questions1 = new question1[10];
static question2[] _questions2 = new question2[10];
static question3[] _questions3 = new question3[10];
static question4[] _questions4 = new question4[10];
static question5[] _questions5 = new question5[10];

static int score = 0;
static int asked = 0;
static int pos = 0;
static int user_input = 0;
static int user_level = 1;

struct question1
{
    public int q_No; 
    public string Question;
    public string Choices;
    public int Answer;
}
```

My reader:

```
static void QuestionReader_Level1()
{
    Console.Clear();
    question1 _question1 = new question1();

    string filename = @"C:\Users\Craigo\Desktop\Quiz_Application\Files\question1.txt";

    while (user_level == 1)
    {
        using (StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(filename, true))
        {
            pos += 1;
            asked += 1;

            _question1.q_No = Convert.ToInt32(sreader.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(_question1.q_No);
            _question1.Question = sreader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(_question1.Question);
            _question1.Choices = sreader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(_question1.Choices);
            _question1.Answer = Convert.ToInt32(sreader.ReadLine());
            user_input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (user_input == _question1.Answer)
            {
                score += 1;
                user_level += 1;
                Console.WriteLine("\nCongratulations, you have scored 1 point and advanced to level 2");
                Console.WriteLine("Score = {0}, Questions Asked = {1}", score, asked);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

the variable "_question1" is not an array:
*question1 _question1 = new question1();*

So, when you have "_question1[pos]", it won't work.

Your array is "_questions1" (you are missing the 's'):
*question1[] _questions1 = new question1[10];*

_questions1[pos] should work

Comment: i followed your advice and it now allows me to write [pos], the program still loops the same question though. it's ignoring pos for some reason, i can get help with it tomorrow. thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score -1):

The while loop only loops when the variable user_level is 1. Also , you have added that if the user's input is equal to the answer , user_level will increment by 1 which will equal to 2 and hence , the loop will not run again. However , the fact that the program is still looping means that the condition was not met , which tells us that THE USER INPUT IS NOT EQUAL TO THE ANSWER. Hence , the error might be caused by the file. Would you mind showing the contents of the file?